# didSelectRowAtIndexPath with several sections

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios5

I have 4 sections in my tableview, and when a row is pressed i want a checkmark to be added to that row. With the code below, if i select a row, some of the other rows also get checked, which is not desired. I'm guessing it has something to do with the several sections, but i don't know how to check for that or fix it. My _allTagsList is a NSMutableArray with 4 dictionaries.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     NSDictionary *dictionary = [_allTagsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
     NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Tags"];
     NSString *selectedTag = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


     if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
     {
         [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }
     else
     {
         [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     }

     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store which indexPaths are selected and then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function you need t also set the accessoryType based on those saved indexPaths.  If you change the accessoryType on a cell and then scroll, as that cell gets recycled the accessoryType will stil remain checked.

Comment: @Niels Sønderbæk Create a property for a mutable array and instantiate it in view did load.  Whenever someone selects a cell check if the index path is already already in the array and if it is remove it and set the cell unchecked.  Otherwise add it and set the cell checked.  Then in cell for row at index path check if the index path is in the array and set the cell checked if it is otherwise set it to not checked.